# Why isn't "using std::xxx" needed for <cmath> functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

For all of the other standard library headers you can include, it is necessary to specify the namespace through any of the following methods:

```
using namespace std;
using std::xxx;
int main() {
    std::xxx;
}
```

The sole exception I've encountered so far is in the `<cmath>` library, when all of their functions I've used thus far do not need any of the above in order to use them without specifying the namespace. Why is that?

Note: I may be wrong that `<cmath>` is the only standard library header that doesn't need the namespace to be specified, or that every function in `<cmath>` behaves like this. I just haven't encountered exceptions to what I've said in daily use yet.

Comment: As @Vlad said, this depends on the implementation you're using. Code that relies on it is not portable.

Comment: The reason for this is that `<cmath>` might not want to (or be allowed to) re-implement everything in the system's C library. So when using C functions in `<cmath>` those functions might become visible to your program. Vlad's quote says that this is ok.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard allows implementations to place names declared in standard C headers in the global namespace.

From the C++ Standard (17.6.1.2 Headers)

> 4. ...In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope
>      (3.3.6) of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names
>      are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then
>      injected into namespace std by  explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).